# How to change default Python version for poetry?

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry, python-3.12

When using Poetry to create a new project with `poetry new project-name`, it consistently defaults to Python 3.10, despite having Python 3.12 installed on my Ubuntu system. Although I managed to configure Python's global version to 3.12, this adjustment occurred after installing Poetry. Consequently, Poetry persists in using Python 3.10 for new projects. Here's the contents of the `pyproject.toml` file that poetry created:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "statements"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Sajid Munawar <iamsajiddev@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I've attempted using `poetry env use path/to/python3.12`, which successfully updates the virtual environment for the current project. However, this command is specific to the current project and doesn't affect future projects created with Poetry.

How can I ensure that Poetry uses Python 3.12 by default for new projects, even after the global Python version has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install Poetry with the specific Python version that you need via `pipx`.

Steps:

1. Uninstall `poetry`.
2. [Install `pipx`](https://pipx.pypa.io/stable/installation/).
3. Install `poetry` with the needed Python version.

   `pipx install --python python3.12 poetry`
4. Create new environments with `poetry` so that `pyproject.toml` has `python = "^3.12"`.

   `poetry new statements`